# How can I add functions to aggregations in groupby in python?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregation

I'm trying to get groupby stats with additional math operations between the aggregations

I tried

```
...agg({
'id':"count",
'repair':"count",
('repair':"count")/('id':"count")
})
```

> ```
> yr    id    repair
> 2016  37    27 
> 2017  53    28
> ```

After grouping I'm able to get this stat by

```
gr['repair']/gr['id']*100
```

> ```
> yr      
> 2016    0.73
> 2017    0.53
> ```

How can I get this type of calculation within the groupby?

Comment: Can you produce a self contained dataset, with your starting point and your expected ouput? Having `2015` randomly appear in the output, and 2016 with additional rows, only adds confusion.

Comment: Please follow @ALollz instructions. Not sure if this is what you wanted, but i think `apply` can help you somehow. Check this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342528/arithmetic-operation-on-a-groupby-pandas-dataframe

Comment: 2015 was some residual typo (edited). I checked the link, it looks similar. Leveragin that to @ALollz question; in that link you can see the operation sample_data_group = sample_data.groupby(['date','part','receipt']), how can I here do an operation inside aggregation, but using the aggregation results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a custom function that returns an aggregated data set:

```
def agg_func(g):
    g['id'] = g['id'].count()
    g['repair'] = g['repair'].count()
    g['repair_per_id'] = (g['repair'] / g['id']) * 100

    return g.aggregate('max')   # CAN ALSO USE: min, max, mean, median, mode 

agg_df = (df.groupby(['group'])
            .apply(agg_func)
            .reset_index(drop=True)
         )
```

---

To demonstrate with seeded, random data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_tools = ['sas', 'stata', 'spss', 'python', 'r', 'julia']

np.random.seed(8192019)
random_df = pd.DataFrame({'group': np.random.choice(data_tools, 500),
                          'id': np.random.randint(1, 10, 500),
                          'repair': np.random.uniform(0, 100, 500)
                         })

# RANDOMLY ASSIGN NANs
random_df['repair'].loc[np.random.choice(random_df.index, 75)] = np.nan

# RUN AGGREGATIONS
agg_df = (random_df.groupby(['group'])
                   .apply(agg_func)
                   .reset_index(drop=True)
         )

print(agg_df)

#     group  id  repair  repair_per_id
# 0   julia  79      70      88.607595
# 1  python  89      74      83.146067
# 2       r  82      69      84.146341
# 3     sas  74      66      89.189189
# 4    spss  77      69      89.610390
# 5   stata  99      84      84.848485
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, thought I thanked but obviously forgot to write :) Thanks again.